# getting the value from column for each field, but it returns NULL?

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I am trying to get the value of "rounds" from the column rounds in my db. So, I want to get the value (1-5) of a field for each debate/post. Based on the value/number it is supposed to display a different thing. When I supposedly get the value It says NULL even though the value in the db field for that debate/post is 4. This is not just that debate, but this occurs for all of them. How can I get the actual value of the field in the column and assign it to a variable called $rounds . This variable needs to have the value for each debate made, not just that debate.

```
<?php
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
}
else{
  $sql = "SELECT rounds FROM vf_Discussion";
    $result = $con->query($sql);

    $allRounds = $result->fetch_row();
    $rounds = $allRounds[0];

    var_dump($rounds);

}
   mysqli_close($con);

      $rounds1 =        '<h2 class="CommentHeading">Round 1 (Pro)</h2> <br> <h2 class="CommentHeading">Round 1 (Con) </h2>';

      $rounds2 =    '<h2 class="CommentHeading">Round 2 (Pro)</h2> <br> <h2 class="CommentHeading">Round 2 (Con)</h2>';

      $rounds3 =    '<h2 class="CommentHeading">Round 3 (Pro)</h2> <br> <h2 class="CommentHeading">Round 3 (Con)</h2>';

      $rounds4 =        '<h2 class="CommentHeading">Round 4 (Pro)</h2> <br> <h2 class="CommentHeading">Round 4 (Con)</h2>';

      $rounds5 =    '<h2 class="CommentHeading">Round 5 (Pro)</h2> <br> <h2 class="CommentHeading">Round 5 (Con)</h2>';

    foreach($allRounds as $rounds) {
        if ($rounds == 1) {
            echo $rounds1;
            foreach ($Sender->Data('Answers') as $Row) {
                $Sender->EventArguments['Comment'] = $Row;
                WriteComment($Row, $Sender, Gdn::Session(), 0);
            }
        }
        if ($rounds == 2) {
            echo $rounds1;
            echo $rounds2;
            foreach ($Sender->Data('Answers') as $Row) {
                $Sender->EventArguments['Comment'] = $Row;
                WriteComment($Row, $Sender, Gdn::Session(), 0);
            }
        }
        if ($rounds == 3) {
            echo $rounds1;
            echo $rounds2;
            echo $rounds3;
            foreach ($Sender->Data('Answers') as $Row) {
                $Sender->EventArguments['Comment'] = $Row;
                WriteComment($Row, $Sender, Gdn::Session(), 0);
            }
        }
        if ($rounds == 4) {
            echo $rounds1;
            echo $rounds2;
            echo $rounds3;
            echo $rounds4;
            foreach ($Sender->Data('Answers') as $Row) {
                $Sender->EventArguments['Comment'] = $Row;
                WriteComment($Row, $Sender, Gdn::Session(), 0);
            }
        }
        if ($rounds == 5) {
            echo $rounds1;
            echo $rounds2;
            echo $rounds3;
            echo $rounds4;
            echo $rounds5;
            foreach ($Sender->Data('Answers') as $Row) {
                $Sender->EventArguments['Comment'] = $Row;
                WriteComment($Row, $Sender, Gdn::Session(), 0);
        }
    }

    }
         ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting the value from column, but returns null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44574090/getting-the-value-from-column-but-returns-null)

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate through object

```
<?php







    $servername = "";
    $username = "";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "";


    $con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if ($con->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
    }
    else{
      $sql = "SELECT rounds FROM vf_Discussion";
        $result = $con->query($sql);


       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {

          var_dump($row);
    }




    }
```

Comment: Doesn't work, can you provide another working solution please?