# getting the value from column, but returns null?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get the value of "rounds" from the column rounds in my data base. So, I want to get the value which is a number of a field for each debate/post. Based on the value/number it is supposed to display a different thing. When I supposedly get the value it says NULL even though the value in the db field for that debate/post is 4. This is not just that debate, but this occurs for all of them. How can I get the actual value of the field in the column and assign it to a variable called $rounds . This variable needs to have the value for each debate made, not just that debate.

```
<?php
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if($con->connect_error)
{
  die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
}
else
{
  $sql = "SELECT rounds FROM vf_Discussion";
  $result = $con->query($sql);

  $allRounds = $result->fetch_row();
  $rounds = $allRounds[0];

  var_dump($rounds);
}

mysqli_close($con);

$rounds1 = '<h2 class="CommentHeading">Round 1 (Pro)</h2> <br> <h2 class="CommentHeading">Round 1 (Con) </h2>';
$rounds2 = '<h2 class="CommentHeading">Round 2 (Pro)</h2> <br> <h2 class="CommentHeading">Round 2 (Con)</h2>';
$rounds3 = '<h2 class="CommentHeading">Round 3 (Pro)</h2> <br> <h2 class="CommentHeading">Round 3 (Con)</h2>';
$rounds4 = '<h2 class="CommentHeading">Round 4 (Pro)</h2> <br> <h2 class="CommentHeading">Round 4 (Con)</h2>';
$rounds5 = '<h2 class="CommentHeading">Round 5 (Pro)</h2> <br> <h2 class="CommentHeading">Round 5 (Con)</h2>';

foreach($allRounds as $rounds)
{
  if($rounds == 1)
  {
    echo $rounds1;
    foreach($Sender->Data('Answers') as $Row)
    {
      $Sender->EventArguments['Comment'] = $Row;
      WriteComment($Row, $Sender, Gdn::Session(), 0);
    }
  }
  if($rounds == 2)
  {
    echo $rounds1;
    echo $rounds2;
    foreach($Sender->Data('Answers') as $Row)
    {
      $Sender->EventArguments['Comment'] = $Row;
      WriteComment($Row, $Sender, Gdn::Session(), 0);
    }
  }
  if($rounds == 3)
  {
    echo $rounds1;
    echo $rounds2;
    echo $rounds3;
    foreach($Sender->Data('Answers') as $Row)
    {
      $Sender->EventArguments['Comment'] = $Row;
      WriteComment($Row, $Sender, Gdn::Session(), 0);
    }
  }
  if($rounds == 4)
  {
    echo $rounds1;
    echo $rounds2;
    echo $rounds3;
    echo $rounds4;
    foreach($Sender->Data('Answers') as $Row)
    {
      $Sender->EventArguments['Comment'] = $Row;
      WriteComment($Row, $Sender, Gdn::Session(), 0);
    }
  }
  if($rounds == 5)
  {
    echo $rounds1;
    echo $rounds2;
    echo $rounds3;
    echo $rounds4;
    echo $rounds5;
    foreach($Sender->Data('Answers') as $Row)
    {
      $Sender->EventArguments['Comment'] = $Row;
      WriteComment($Row, $Sender, Gdn::Session(), 0);
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: not sure why you are using all of those 'if's. you better use a simpler code like this:$result = mysql_query("SELECT rounds FROM vf_Discussion");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['column'];
  ....
  }

Comment: @mele , still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [PDO](http://php.net/manual/de/book.pdo.php)s. Your mistake was in the assignment of `$rounds`.
And I cleaned up your code for better readability:

```
<?php
$servername = "";
$dbname = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";

$pdo = NULL;

try
{
  $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $servername . ';dbname=' . $dbname, $username, $password);
  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $exception)
{
  die("Connection failed: " . $exception->getMessage());
}

$rounds = []; // array we want to save all the rounds to

// the database
$query = "SELECT rounds, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM vf_Discussion GROUP BY rounds ORDER BY rounds";
$statement = $pdo->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();

$rows = $statement->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($rows as $row)
{
  $rounds[] = ['name' => $row['rounds'], 'count' => $row['cnt']];
}

foreach($rounds as $round)
{
  $name = $round['name'];
  $cnt = $round['cnt'];

  echo '<h2 class="CommentHeading">Round ' . $round . ' (Pro)</h2> <br> <h2 class="CommentHeading">Round ' . $round . ' (Con)</h2> <br> <h2 class="CommentHeading">Number of Rounds ' . $cnt . '</h2>';

  foreach($Sender->Data('Answers') as $Row)
  {
    $Sender->EventArguments['Comment'] = $Row;
    WriteComment($Row, $Sender, Gdn::Session(), 0);
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: After implementing, it returns all the ifs, so, round 1, round 1 round 2, round 1 round 2 round 3, round 1 round 2 round 3 round 4, you get it now. How can I fix this?

Comment: Now it just repeats never ending or almost never ending "rounds (PRO)". Am I supposed to replace all the code you gave before with the edited or just a snippet? if snippet, which part?

Comment: @julereca do you want just 5 rounds?

Comment: I want the amount of rounds to be whatever number is in the database field , (1-5).

Comment: @julereca I edited the code again. Now the query returns every round just a single time in the right order. I hope that this is what you need. But I already solved your issue with returning null ..

Comment: now it shows all 5 rounds. The db field is 4. I want it to show the amount which is in the db. How can I do this? Thanks for all your help so far!

Comment: @julereca **please accept my answer** to your question here on stackoverflow.
if you need to do a different task, open a new question. but only if you really can't figure it out by yourself

Comment: Can you please edit the code so it shows whatever amount of rounds (1-5) are in the db?

Comment: next time you should provide the database schema if it could help to answer your question.

Comment: Hi Phil, I'm sorry about that, can you still edit the code to make it rely on the db?

Comment: @julereca I added the number of rounds. Now it's up to you to present the number as you like.

Comment: That just broke the whole website. Did I have to change any part of that code?

Comment: the FROM-tag was missing. **I edited the code again.** You should fix errors like this on your own by reading the error message on your screen and maybe search online for answers

Comment: Now it has 6 sets of "Round Array (Pro)

Round Array (Con)

Number of Rounds "

Comment: It give you one set for each kind of round entry. I can't control what's in your database

Comment: The DB field for that debate/post is 4 rounds, the value is 4. So, it should display that amount of rounds.

Comment: The query counts the number of debates/posts/entries in `vf_Discussion` for each value of `rounds` in the database.

Comment: The idea with StackOverflow is that you code something, if you get issues, you ask for help and we try and help. **We do not write _YOUR_ code for free**. I will not comment on this question anymore.

Comment: Can you please assist me and tell me what to do in order to accomplish my goal?

Comment: you _need to_ invest time.. 1. learn PHP [here](http://www.hackingwithphp.com/) or [here](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/php) 2. [get a good editor](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/sublime-text-3-for-php-developers) 3. practice in small steps on small projects like a calculator _AND_ **close this question by accepting my answer** to appreciate my efforts :P